# How can display this response of Image URL in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, networking

This is the response of ImageList i have.

How Can i display this postURL array in UI, may be image.network with Builder like
GridView or ListView Builder.

```
 "postUrl": [
            "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/265_0.jpg",
            "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/265_1.JPG",
            "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/265_2.PNG",
            "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/265_3.PNG"
        ],
```

If implemented all model and try to display it, but i am getting some codec and not valid error.

Please Help friends.

Comment: This is the error if i replace the '[' and ']'.

HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/266_0.PNG%20https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/266_1.png%20https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/266_2.png%5D

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the response from the API, you would store it as a list. Then update the UI through list iterable with flutter NetworkImage widget.

The image you are trying to display you image in column

```dart
Column(
  children: postUrl.map((url) => NetworkImage(url: url)).toList(),
);
```